# Main menu hidden before the visitor moves the mouse

Tags: html, css

I want to do this:

I have got website with video-background. And i want to have **hidden main menu until the visitor moves the mouse**. Once the **mouse is moved, it will remain visible** forever.

Menu is in separated file: 'header.inc.php'

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#Uvod"><img src="img/logo.jpg" width="100%"></a>
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar" >
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#o-nas">O SPOLEČNOSTI</a></li>
        <li><a href="#sluzby">SLUŽBY</a></li>
        <li><a href="#reference">REFERENCE</a></li>
        <li><a href="#kontakt">KONTAKT</a></li></ul>
    </div> </div></nav>
```

[Link to jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s9au2u9o/1/#&togetherjs=oz3TCQ0a4n)

Comment: you mean anywhere in the website the mouse move show the menu ?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please share your code and create a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) to show where you got stuck.

Comment: We need an online example to test it. Use you can not post it, post a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net) please.

Comment: @M.Tanzil
No, only on homepage.

Comment: @caramba

Like this? My first day on stackoverflow, so be patient please. 
https://jsfiddle.net/s9au2u9o/1/#&togetherjs=oz3TCQ0a4n

Answer (score 1):

While it'd be great to get an example, I've put a quick JSFiddle together for you which demonstrates one simple approach: https://jsfiddle.net/tmaLjsvu/1/

Detecting mouse movement is fairly easy with jQuery, and you can use `$(document).mousemove` to detect any mouse movement across the whole page.

This example simply adds a class to your menu, which changes it from `display:none` to `display:block`.

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

This is all you need:

```
$(window).one( "mousemove", function() {
$('#hidr, #showr').fadeIn(1000);
});
```

Link to pen:

http://codepen.io/damianocel/pen/YWaWJE

Targets the 2 menu buttons, adapt it to your code. You can set the menues opacity to 0 on load, to preventt he fadeIn jump of the other contect as well, up to you.